# Prestashop: Uncaught Error: Class 'smartblog' not found in

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am working on a case with Prestashop, should be simple, proved to be way more frustrating in reality.

I've bought a theme "Coin Store" from the store; Installed the latest compatible version (1.6.1.20), works fine. After installing the theme via the backend, it errors the complete front-end.
See: http://hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl

Tried working out the problem but no luck so far.

**Errors:**

*Frontend:*

Fatal HTTP 500.

*Backend (phplog)*

`AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class . 'smartblog' not found in /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/cache/smarty/compile/35/e8/e1/35e8e1691ccf2a123867db9c3a4ceea285120369.file.blockpermanentlinks-header.tpl.php:47\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(188): content_5bedcc3b7147a3_40989013(Object(Smarty_Custom_Template))\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/classes/SmartyCustom.php(317): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch(Object(Smarty_Custom_Template), NULL, NULL, NULL, false, true, false)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/classes/module/Module.php(2309): Smarty_Custom_Template->fetch()\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.php(60): ModuleCore->display('/var/www/vhosts...', 'blockpermanentl...', 'blockpermanentl...')\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/hondtong.dev.cbyte.nl/httpdocs/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlink...\n'`

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the theme author? You paid for something that's not working.

Comment: @Cmaster, works with PrestaShop is really simple, as long as you don't install templates or modules that break something, as is your case at this time, especially if what you are installing does not have security validations. I have tried to use smartblog in the past and it simply was not possible, until trying to remove it completely it was complicated for me.

Comment: I did @PatrickQ, got some loosy info, not very helpfull. They said, reinstall your demo-data

Comment: Well, agreed by now, @Rolige. Problem is customer loved the theme, so i am making an effort getting it working ;)